# treeview code with fixed directory

Tags: c#, winforms, treeviewitem

i need help with this piece of code to get files from directory and populate them in treeview.

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
{
    TreeNode node = TreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(directory.Name);
    node.ImageIndex = 1;


    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            TreeNode nodes = TreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes(node.Index).Nodes.Add(file.Name);
            nodes.ImageIndex = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

i get this error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.Nodes.get'`

i appreciate any kind of help thanks

Comment: Looks like the error would be generated on the first line after the initial foreach...  TreeView is a class name and probably not the name of your object.  What is the TreeView object named?

Comment: Try replacing the name `TreeView` with the actual name of the control.

Answer (score 3):

`TreeView` is not a static class which is why you're getting that error message. You should change where you've used `TreeView` to the actual name of your instance.

For example:

```
TreeNode node = TreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(directory.Name);
```

should be

```
//myTreeView is the name of my TreeView object
TreeNode node = myTreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(directory.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want it this.

```
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\users");
foreach (string directoryName in directories)
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
    var node = new TreeNode(directory.Name);
    node.ImageIndex = 1;

    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            var nodes = node.Nodes.Add(file.Name);
            nodes.ImageIndex = 2;
        }
    }
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help it worked awsome. i need help in the following, i have Form2 with adobe pdf reader tool in it, and some of the files in Form1 are pdf, how can i preview the pdf files in treeview in Form1 in adobe pdf reader in Form2

Comment: Glad it worked for you. As for the Adobe Reader, the question isn't related to this thread but you can look into "Adobe Reader ActiveX Control". There is a good article a this link which shows you exactly how to do this. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hirendra_singh/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-C-Sharp/ :)